# Соединение 2-х docker контейнеров unoconv , Libreoffice

Tags: python, docker, open-office, libre-office

[Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/PywrCZkK) Мне надо поднимать `unoconv`(использует `Libreoffice/Soffice/OpenOffice`) приложение в одном контейнере в слушающем режиме (серверном) на определенном порту, затем пробросить этот порт на внешнюю машину, и сделать так чтобы можно было достучаться из других контейнеров по этому порту к серверу unoconv.

---

[Вот работа](https://pastebin.com/UDfgyyh3) с первым контейнером(запуск в слушающем режиме):

1) я хочу пробросить внутренний порт контейнера на `2004` внешний.

2) `ifconfig` показывает такой адрес `172.17.0.2`

---

[Вот работа](https://pastebin.com/ELgXmZSi) со вторым контейнером(попытка подключения к экземпляру `unoconv` в существующем контейнере):

Думаю следует обратить внимание на это:

```
MacBook-Air-Nikita:~ user$ docker run --expose=2004 -p 2004:2004 -v /Users/user/Desktop/:/Users/user/Desktop/ -it avsw/libreoffice_container:v1 /bin/bash
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint romantic_kirch (1e02fc65cb59635f7dfa083f843ce84ff1907b17c0b459f43638d7fdf4928cda): Bind for 0.0.0.0:2004 failed: port is already allocated.
MacBook-Air-Nikita:~ user$ docker run --expose=2004 -v /Users/user/Desktop/:/Users/user/Desktop/ -it avsw/libreoffice_container:v1 /bin/bash
```

По всей видимости я не правильно подключаюсь к порту с которым работает серверный контейнер ? `ifconfig` показывает `inet 172.17.0.3`

Итак попытка подключения к другому контейнеру не увенчалась успехом:

```
[root@ca0e93d2559b /]# unoconv -vvv -p 2004 -f odt /Users/user/Desktop/собеседование.pdf
Verbosity set to level 3
Using office base path: /usr/lib64/libreoffice
Using office binary path: /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program
DEBUG: Connection type: socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2004,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext
DEBUG: Existing listener not found.
DEBUG: Launching our own listener using /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin.
LibreOffice listener successfully started. (pid=50)
Input file: /Users/user/Desktop/собеседование.pdf
Selected output format: ODF Text Document [.odt]
Selected office filter: writer8
Used doctype: document
Output file: file:///Users/user/Desktop/%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%90%C2%B1%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%90%C2%B4%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%90%C2%B2%C3%90%C2%B0%C3%90%C2%BD%C3%90%C2%B8%C3%90%C2%B5.odt
unoconv: UnoException during export phase:
Unable to store document to file:///Users/user/Desktop/%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%90%C2%B1%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%90%C2%B4%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%90%C2%B2%C3%90%C2%B0%C3%90%C2%BD%C3%90%C2%B8%C3%90%C2%B5.odt (ErrCode 283)

Properties: ((com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue){ Name = (string)"FilterName", Handle = (long)0x0, Value = (any){ (string)"writer8" }, State = (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState)DIRECT_VALUE }, (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue){ Name = (string)"OutputStream", Handle = (long)0x0, Value = (any){ (com.sun.star.uno.XInterface)0x3f477f8{, supportedInterfaces={com.sun.star.lang.XTypeProvider,com.sun.star.io.XOutputStream}} }, State = (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState)DIRECT_VALUE }, (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue){ Name = (string)"Overwrite", Handle = (long)0x0, Value = (any){ (boolean)true }, State = (com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState)DIRECT_VALUE })
DEBUG: Terminating LibreOffice instance.
DEBUG: Waiting for LibreOffice instance to exit.
```

И даже так:

```
[root@ca0e93d2559b /]# unoconv -vvv -p 2004 -s 172.17.0.2 -f odt /Users/user/Desktop/собеседование.pdf
Verbosity set to level 3
Using office base path: /usr/lib64/libreoffice
Using office binary path: /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program
DEBUG: Connection type: socket,host=172.17.0.2,port=2004,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext
DEBUG: Existing listener not found.
DEBUG: Launching our own listener using /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin.
LibreOffice listener successfully started. (pid=72)
Failed to connect to /usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin (pid=72) in 6 seconds.
Connector : couldn't connect to socket (Success)
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

Нужна помощь, как подключить контейнеры к друг другу ?

Comment: причём здесь питон? Вы хотите из одного контейнера к другому по сети обратиться? Они по умолчанию уже соединены. К примеру, чтобы слушать на 2004 порту (сервер): `docker run --rm -p 2004 alpine nc -l -p 2004`. Чтобы узнать какой ip используется: `docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" $(docker ps -q)`. Чтобы послать запрос (клиент): `docker run -i --rm alpine nc 172.17.0.2 2004 <<<abc`, где 172.17.0.2 это пример, что docker inspect может вернуть.  Можно свою сеть создать, подключить контейнер к нескольким сетям итд (`docker network`)

Answer (score 1):

1) Выкинуть порт на host, дальше разрешить удаленное соединения к этому порту

2) Надо сделать одну сеть - bridge.
Используй docker-compose или вручную создай сети и пропиши контейнерам.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  one:
    networks:
      - net
    port:
      - 2004:2004
  two:
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.0.0/16
```

Таким образом в two на ip 172.22.0.1 будет host c нужным 2004.

Также можно использовать dns - one.project_net.

```
one - название service

project - название проекта (нижнее подчеркивания игнорируются)

net - название сети
```

Название проекта меняем в `.env` c `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project`.